# How to fix unused variable eslint error without declaring it

Tags: typescript, types, eslint, typescript-typings

```
type ProductImageProps = {
  variant?: "big" | "small",
  imageUrl?: string,
  id: number,
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  addProductToCart?: (id: number) => void
};
```

I have an type definition of a function which takes in an argument, but does not return anything. ESlint is throwing me an unused variable error for this. Is there another way in typescript to define type for the function here?

PS: I don't want to switch off the unused variable error, its really useful in rest of the application dev.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You can't have unused vars in type definitions. It must be something else that is causing that warning. Would need more details or if possible a full repo for a reproducible example.

Comment: Did you find what was the problem?